# How to iterate over loist to make its values as my nested dict in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested

I am not moving forward and need som help (I'm new to coding)

I have the following structure:

`sim = {'S1': {}, 'S2': {}, 'S3': {}, 'S4': {}, 'S5': {}}`

and a list
`sim_list = [1,2,3,4,5]`

my result should look like this:

`sim = {'S1': {"number": 1}, 'S2': {"number": 2}, 'S3': {"number": 3}, 'S4': {"number": 4}, 'S5': {"number": 5}}`

my attempt:

```
for key in sim.keys():
    for i in sim_list:
        sim[key]= {"number":i}
```

but i only get inner dicts with {"number":5}:

`sim = {'S1': {"number": 5}, 'S2': {"number": 5}, 'S3': {"number": 5}, 'S4': {"number": 5}, 'S5': {"number": 5}}`

so how can i iterate over the list objects to go to their respective place?

Comment: You've already got an answer that will work, but in case you're wondering why **your** code doesn't work, it's because you are overwriting `sim[key]` every iteration over `sim_list`, so that you'll only ever get the final number in `sim_list` as your `number` value. You need to select a number based on the key (like in the answer you got).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dict comprehension:

```
sim = {'S1': {}, 'S2': {}, 'S3': {}, 'S4': {}, 'S5': {}}
sim_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

output = {list(sim)[i]: {"number": sim_list[i]} for i in range(len(sim))}
print(output)
```

The equivalent without dict comprehension would be:

```
output = {}
for i in range(len(sim)):
    output[list(sim)[i]] = {"number": sim_list[i] }
print(output)
```

---

It is also possible to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), to associate each key and item together:

```
for key, num in zip(sim.keys(), sim_list):
    sim[key] = {"number": num}
print(sim)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could build the dictionary from scratch using a dictionary comprehension thus:

```
sim = {f'S{i}': {'number': i} for i in range(1, 6)}

print(sim)
```

**Output:**

```
{'S1': {'number': 1}, 'S2': {'number': 2}, 'S3': {'number': 3}, 'S4': {'number': 4}, 'S5': {'number': 5}}
```